# What is the subject here?

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement

I am confused about this sentence: do I use *do* or *does*?

Will it depend on what the subject is? Which is the correct one?

> 1. What **do** your best friend's parents do?
> 2. What **does** your best friend's parents do?

What is the subject here?

Comment: "Parents" is the subject.  "Parents" is plural.  Therefore, by the English Law of Conservation of S Characters, it would be "do".

Comment: Did you mean the target Which asked for is parents ( plural "they"), so the correct answer with auxiliary do.

Comment: *Parents* → *do*; *parent* → *does*.

Answer (score 2):

The subject is "your best friend's **parents**".
This is plural ("parents"), so 1 is correct.